# Certify The Web - CheckDNS error resolving DnsSecRecursiveDdnsResolver?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certify

I have installed Certify SSL/TLS Certificate Manager 4.0.8.0 onto my windows server. I am trying to add a wildcard certificate for *.staging1.mydomain.co.nz

When I click Test, it tells me that CheckDNS has resolved to an IP Address, and it tells me that I have created the TXT record successfully.

However, I am getting an error on one of the DNS checks:
CheckDNS error resolving DnsSecRecursiveDdnsResolver. Count not resolve staging1.mydomain.co.nz

My websites are hosted at websitecode.staging1.mydomain.co.nz

What do I need to do to get this to work?

[image: certify the web]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of this app.

The success of the DNS checks can vary on a per-server basis depending on your own DNS setup and firewalls. By default DNS checks should be disabled in the app, so if you didn't enable them yourself please let me know so I can investigate if it's a bug.

To disable the DNS checks go to Settings and uncheck Enable DNS Validation Checks. We should probably make this one a warning rather than an error.

Any further issues please go ahead an open a bug on github 
 (https://github.com/webprofusion/certify) or a question on the community forum (https://community.certifytheweb.com/